# How to add a note or comment into a formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

#### Microsoft Excel

Microsoft Excel has this feature where one can add a note into a formula with the `N()` function. It looks like this:

[image]

Source: [Add Comments to a Formula in Excel for Your Future Reference, Lifehacker.com](https://lifehacker.com/add-comments-to-a-formula-in-excel-for-your-future-refe-510113024)

#### Google Sheets

Does Google Sheets have a similar feature to embed notes and comments into a formula?

I'm not talking about the [`concatenate`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) function which is something different than what I mean.

I'm also not talking about the ["Insert comment"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65129?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) feature which is also different.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can have the same functionality in sheets as well.

```
&T(N("comment"))
```

OR

```
=IFERROR(A1/A2,"") &T(N("comment"))
```

OR

```
=YourFormula+N("comment")
```

*(This last one works when the formula gives numeric results)*

Answer (score 4):

I found that none of the solutions I found for this question worked for my specific situation, so I did some research and testing and found my own solution.

I want to add multiple comments to a formula in a single Google Sheets cell. I found I could use this function to do it:

```
code("Insert comment here")*0
```

Here's a usage example:

[image]

There are likely other ways to achieve the same thing (converting a string to a zero number so it will have no effect on the formula), but I stopped at the first one I found because it's all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a slightly more elegant way of using comments taking advantage of the [`LET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535) function.

An example with your formula would be:

```
=LET(
  comment,
  "This is a sample comment on a formula",

  SUM(B2:B3)
)
```

Note I use vertical spacing and indentation to improve readability, but you can just write the formula in a single line.

#### Explanation

The `LET` function takes pairs of names and definitions, and a last argument that is then evaluated taking into account the definition in previous arguments. The signature is something like:

```
LET(name1, value1, [name2, value2], […], expression)
```

We just define a name `comment` with the actual comment as its value, but we never actually use it in the expression. Note that the name `comment` is just for convinience, and you can just use any valid name you want instead.

Comment: I think that [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/140961/) is still the "proper" approach, but nice alternative approach.

Comment: @BlindSpots one thing I don't like from that answer is that the syntax depends on the type of calculation (number vs string). My approach just ignores the comment and it's never added to any calculation. But I guess it's just a matter of preference :)

Comment: Both solutions run the risk of introducing typo-related errors, especially if commenting is spread out throughout the formula.  A plus for your approach is when troubleshooting code the comments can also be selectively called/displayed in the output.  I continue to like your alternative approach.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your code. I did a small adjustments, so the 0 will replaced with nothing.

```
SUBSTITUTE(
  code(
    "NOTE: RESET Work Calculation Code"
  )*0
;0;"")
```